# How does NSArray and Core Data with a non-persistent store work from a memory perspective?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, uiimage

This is a rather simple question, but I haven't been able to pinpoint a clear answer in my searching.

If I have an `NSArray`, and add fifty 1MB `UIImage`s to it, where does that 50MB get deducted from? Will the app be using 50MB more memory? Will it simply store it on the disk?

The same goes for Core Data where instead of using a persistent store I store it in memory. Would the size of the Core Data store take up exactly that much memory/RAM or would it live on the disk and be wiped when the app finishes executing?

I'm concerned whether or not I should be storing several dozen megabytes in `UIImage`s in an `NSArray`, or if I should be using `NSCache` (I'd rather not as I'd prefer to never lose any of the images).

Comment: Keep as few images as you can in memory. You will use more ram than the raw image data. It's only written to disk if you do something to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have an NSArray, and add fifty 1MB UIImages to it, where does
>   that 50MB get deducted from? Will the app be using 50MB more memory?

**Yes.**

> Will it simply store it on the disk?

**No.** Arrays are stored in memory.

> The same goes for Core Data where instead of using a persistent store
>   I store it in memory. Would the size of the Core Data store take up
>   exactly that much memory/RAM or would it live on the disk and be wiped
>   when the app finishes executing?

**Yes,** if you tell Core Data to story everything in memory, that's exactly what it'll do.

The line between "memory" and "disk" can get a little fuzzy if you consider that virtual memory systems can swap pages of real memory out to disk and read them back when they're needed. That's not an issue for iOS, however, as [iOS doesn't provide a VM backing store](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/performance/conceptual/managingmemory/articles/aboutmemory.html) and writeable memory is never swapped out.

> I'm concerned whether or not I should be storing several dozen
>   megabytes in UIImages in an NSArray, or if I should be using NSCache

Those aren't your only options, of course. You could store the images in files and read them in as needed. You should be thoughtful about the way your app uses both memory and disk space, of course, but you also need to consider network use, battery use, and performance. Storing data on disk is often preferable to downloading it again because downloading takes time, may impact the user's data plan, and uses a lot more energy than just reading data from secondary storage.

Comment: How do libraries such as [`SDWebImage`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) then make claims that "A guarantee that the same URL won't be downloaded several times". What happens to the URL after you download it once? If I download several hundred images, is it going to potentially use several hundred MB of RAM?

Comment: @DougSmith According to the project, SDWebImage provides "An asynchronous memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling". I don't think that guarantee is set in stone -- if you've downloaded so many images that the one you want is evicted from the cache, it'll have to be downloaded again.